# How can I solve for x where $10^{10000} = x^x$

Tags: exponential-function

I hope this is not too elementary a question to post on here.  If so, apologies.
I'm stumped how I would solve for x where $10^{10000} = x^x$.
Thanks!

Comment: Using common logarithm on both sides gives $10000 = x\log_{10} x$ But nothing more came to my mind.

Comment: Definitely not "elementary"!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can express the solution using [Lambert's W function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function), but in practice you'd find it numerically. Take logs on both sides to get
$$ 10000 = x \log_{10}(x) $$
and use bisection or Newton-Raphson to approximate the solution.